# RxJava: auto unsubscribe in Android MVP

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp

i use `RxJava`/`Retrofit` in Android App with MVP Pattern.

now i want to clean the `xxxPresenter` when the `Activity/Fragment` destroy for prevent `oom`.

the Presenter simple code:

```
public class LoginPresenter {

    private LoginView mLoginView;
    private LoginMode mLoginMode;
    private Subscriber mLoginSubscriber;

    public LoginPresenter(LoginView loginView) {
        this.mLoginView = loginView;
        mLoginMode = new LoginMode();
    }

    void login(String userName, String pwd) {
        mLoginSubscriber = new Subscriber() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                if (mLoginView != null) {
                    mLoginView.onLoginSuccess();
                }
            }
        };
        mLoginMode.login(userName, pwd, mLoginSubscriber);
    }

    void destory() {
        mLoginView = null;
        mLoginSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

when the Activity/Fragment destory will call presenter's destory() method

my problem is：

if a presenter has more network request i will hold a lot of subscriber members, has any way to let the subscriber auto unsubscribe when `Activity/Fragment` destory?

Comment: maybe use this: https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need is `CompositeSubscription`.  It is a container for subscriptions which allows you to unsubscribe them all at once.

```
public class LoginPresenter {

    private LoginView mLoginView;
    private LoginMode mLoginMode;
    private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;

    public LoginPresenter(LoginView loginView) {
        this.mLoginView = loginView;
        mLoginMode = new LoginMode();
        mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    }

    void login(String userName, String pwd) {
        Subscription loginSubscriber = new Subscriber() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                if (mLoginView != null) {
                    mLoginView.onLoginSuccess();
                }
            }
        };
        mLoginMode.login(userName, pwd, loginSubscriber);
        mSubscriptions.add(loginSubscriber);
    }

    void destory() {
        mLoginView = null;
        mSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look also to CompositeDisposable